# How to read complicated .txt file and transform to JSON

Tags: python, r, json, matlab

I need to extract information from a txt file generated by our MRT scanner, to then convert the information into a JSON file with a specific structure.
The text file is not a datafile, but an actual text file containing information about that scan session. Can anybody put me on the right path on how one would go about this?

Below an example of part of the files contents. I'd prefer to do it in R, but MATLAB, or Python are possibilities, too.

```
Example:

Image filter =          "system default";
Uniformity correction =     "no";
Geometry correction =       "default";
IF_info_seperator =     0;
Total scan duration =       "09:05.0";
Rel. SNR =          0.752056241;
Act. TR (ms) =          "5000";
Act. TE (ms) =          "74";
ACQ matrix M x P =      "96 x 94";
ACQ voxel MPS (mm) =        "2.50 / 2.55 / 2.50";
REC voxel MPS (mm) =        "2.50 / 2.50 / 2.50";
Scan percentage (%) =       97.9166641;
```

Comment: It's possible to do in R, but text parsing in any language is very dependent on the **exact** structure of your file, and just because something works on a small example like this in no way guarantees it will work on your actual files. An important thing that is missing is showing how each observation (like the block above) are separated in your code. This is important, because it will need to be recognised by a parser in order to nest your JSON properly. A longer and more realistic example is probably needed for anyone to have any confidence that a solution is likely to work.

Comment: hi, thank you for your response. what exactly do you mean by "how each observation ... are separated in your code"?

Comment: if the text file only contains information about a single scanning session you can ignore that, but if it contains several, then it becomes important to know how they are separated within the file. From reading your comments under jay's answer, it sounds as though the solution for your example didn't work out with the actual text file, which is what I was warning would happen in my initial comment. All it takes to break jay's code is a single line that contains no equal sign, or an extra equals sign somewhere. You really need to share the whole file to get a working solution.

Comment: yeah you're right, the output is too unstable. I think I'll come up with a new plan =) thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R, using `readLines`, `gsub` and colleagues.

```
## read raw lines; don't warn "final line" (might have unwanted side-effects) 
txt <- readLines("mri.txt", warn=FALSE)
## replace first `=` with `§` and split there
spl <- strsplit(sub("=", "§", txt), "§")
## expand lengths of list elements to 2 (throws a `NA` in case)
spl <- lapply(spl, `length<-`, 2)
## remove leading/trailing whitespace; make matrix
tmp <- t(sapply(spl, trimws))
## replace `;` or `"` with empty string,
tmp[,2] <- gsub(";|\"", "", tmp[,2])
tmp
#       [,1]                    [,2]                
#  [1,] "Image filter"          "system default"    
#  [2,] "Uniformity correction" "no"                
#  [3,] "Geometry correction"   "default"           
#  [4,] "IF_info_seperator"     "0"                 
#  [5,] "Total scan duration"   "09:05.0"           
#  [6,] "Rel. SNR"              "0.752056241"       
#  [7,] "Act. TR (ms)"          "5000"              
#  [8,] "Act. TE (ms)"          "74"                
#  [9,] "ACQ matrix M x P"      "96 x 94"           
# [10,] "ACQ voxel MPS (mm)"    "2.50 / 2.55 / 2.50"
# [11,] "REC voxel MPS (mm)"    "2.50 / 2.50 / 2.50"
# [12,] "Scan percentage (%)"   "97.9166641"
```

And finally `jsonlite::toJSON`.

```
library(jsonlite)
toJSON(tmp)
[["Image filter","system default"],["Uniformity correction","no"],["Geometry correction","default"],["IF_info_seperator","0"],["Total scan duration","09:05.0"],["Rel. SNR","0.752056241"],["Act. TR (ms)","5000"],["Act. TE (ms)","74"],["ACQ matrix M x P","96 x 94"],["ACQ voxel MPS (mm)","2.50 / 2.55 / 2.50"],["REC voxel MPS (mm)","2.50 / 2.50 / 2.50"],["Scan percentage (%)","97.9166641"]]
```

Of course you'll probably need to fine-tune this.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! 
Could you maybe explain line 3 
tmp[,2] <- gsub(";|\"", "", tmp[,2])?
When I run your code, it does read the lines, but it doesn't split it into 2 columns...trying to understand why...

Comment: @Dugmic The `gsub` replaces `;` or `"` with `""`= empty string, where `|` is an "or" and the `"` needs to be escaped by a backslash because it has a special meaning. Hm, I copy-pasted your example into a .txt file, saved it and it worked. Maybe try `strsplit(txt, "=")` w/o spaces around the equal sign? PS: I also assumed that `Example:` and the empty line below don't belong  to the file content.

Comment: thanks so much for the explanation! that makes sense =) and your tip did the trick! only thing that is left is that I get an error message saying "incomplete final line found on 'mri.txt'", even though the script does its job perfectly.

Comment: sadly, when running over the entire file it gives me a really weird output where tmp[,1] either says character[1] or character[2] and tmp[,2] is each of the lines.

Comment: @jay.sf I think you're brave taking this on. There are too many things in the unseen part of the actual text file that could break any working solution to the example. +1 for effort though.

Comment: @Dugmic The "final line" issue is just a warning, simply stating that there's a line break missing. Try to go to a file at the very last line, make a line break and save it. You can probably ignore this completely and set `warn=FALSE`. 
Your `character,X` issue comes from the `sapply` when the `strsplit` didn't work well: if there's no `=`, it just yields one element, where we need two, so we extend the lengths. Or if there's an `=` at the RHS we just want the split at the first occurrence, so we use `sub` to replace the first one with sth else (`§` should not occur otherwise). See edits.

Comment: @jay.sf thank you for your effort! your edit worked great =)!!